# Master branch is missing after I created a new repository in Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

In the past when I created a git repository and at the first push I could implicitly created the master branch too.

But now something not okay.

I have created a repository on Bitbucket.
Then in my source folder I run the `git init` then `git remote add origin https://[repository-url-mine]` and after `git add .` and `git commit -m "Init"` commands were run.
But when I want to push it, the git says, it did not found any master branch.

Did I miss something? I checked the Bitbucket page, but if I follow the commands from the code snippet, I get the same errors.

Or am I wrong how to use `git push origin master` command?

```
Here the full error message:
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://[myname]@bitbucket.org/[myname]/project.git'
```

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: Full error message is added in description

Comment: What is shown for `git branch -a`?

Comment: Well, I could solve this problem. On the online bitbucket.org I commited a Readme.md then it automatically created the master branch, and I could use it with it.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz Strange, `git branch -a` does not give me any branch either. What would be the right way to get the origin master?